# How to get unique list from multiple arrays in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, unique, pymongo

Let say I have thousands of similar entries in my MongoDB

```
{
    "_id": "1",
    "data": {
        "people": [
            {
                "id": "234323432"
            },
            {
                "id": "44213126"
            },
            {
                "id": "1321452"
            }
        ],
        "guys": [
            {
                "id": "521452"
            },
            {
                "id": "92321452"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want get all of people and guys IDs (from the arrays) and group them to get only unique list of them. Is this possible to do this only in the MongoDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you want your output to be, map reduce is definitely the way to go. Here is a simple one that will take your documents above, isolate the unique ids, and count the occurrence of each one:

```
map = function() {
    this.data.people.forEach(function(id){
        emit(id, {count:1});
    });
    this.data.guys.forEach(function(id){
        emit(id, {count:1});
    });
};
reduce = function(key, values) {
  var total = 0;
  values.forEach(function(value) {
        total += value.count;
  });
  return {count: total};
};
db.test.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out: 'result'});
```

If your data set was:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "data" : { "people" : [ { "id" : "234323432" }, { "id" : "44213126" }, { "id" : "1321452" } ], "guys" : [ { "id" : "521452" }, { "id" : "92321452" } ] } }
{ "_id" : 2, "data" : { "people" : [ { "id" : "234323432" }, { "id" : "44213126" }, { "id" : "1321452" } ], "guys" : [ { "id" : "521452" }, { "id" : "92321452" } ] } }
{ "_id" : 3, "data" : { "people" : [ { "id" : "234323432" }, { "id" : "44213126" }, { "id" : "1321452" } ], "guys" : [ { "id" : "521452" }, { "id" : "92321452" } ] } }
```

Running:

```
db.test.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out: 'result'});
```

will yield a collection named 'result' that has the following in it:

```
{ "_id" : { "id" : "1321452" }, "value" : { "count" : 3 } }
{ "_id" : { "id" : "234323432" }, "value" : { "count" : 3 } }
{ "_id" : { "id" : "44213126" }, "value" : { "count" : 3 } }
{ "_id" : { "id" : "521452" }, "value" : { "count" : 3 } }
{ "_id" : { "id" : "92321452" }, "value" : { "count" : 3 } }
```

You can mold the above to how you want to represent your data or what you want to do with it, but hope this helps you along your way.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to dive into mongo's MapReduce:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce

Answer (score 0):

You can merge them at the client. Depending on what language you use, it can range from very simple to easy.

Comment: Of course I can do that, but that will bypass the beauty of doing it in MongoDB

Comment: Well, it depends on your definition of beauty. If you ask Mongo to do it: it is more work done by the server. Since you will be downloading all the data anyways, it may be worthwhile to pass the processing burden to the client. It really depends upon your architecture.